# I cannot bridge a connection between Access (Office365) and java (netbeans)

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, office365, ucanaccess

I was tasked to use an access database as the method of permanent storage in a Netbeans java project.  It was suggested that we use Ucanaccess which I tried, but I was unable to establish a connection.

I have tried the following tutorials:

1. http://wiki.netbeans.org/ConnectingToMsAccessDB
2. https://www.tutorialsfield.com/how-to-connect-ms-access-database-in-java/
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhuafZrlWq4
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFr1Gf78l2Y

Non of which worked.  When I tried to do the control panel connection under ODBC data sources under System DSN, nothing showed up. (I tried both the 32bit and 64bit versions).  When I contacted my teacher she told me that connections aren't made in windows anymore, and that we code the "bridge" in java.

[This is how the System DSN looks when I click add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7FXe.png)

Can anyone please explain to me how to do this?

This is my current code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class access
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            try{
              Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");//Loading Driver
              Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\marco\\Desktop\\stocktracker.accdb");//Establishing Connection
              System.out.println("Connected Successfully");

          }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println("Error in connection");

          }
    }

}
```

[This is what the exception looks like that I get when running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unDkD.png)

Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390)?

Comment: Thank you Gord Tompson.  I just followed that answer and it worked.  Thanks for linking me to it!  Connection successful